# Swiping left to create a new collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement a smoother way for a use to add new `collectionViewCells` for `myCollectionView` (which only shows one cell at a time). I want it to be something like when the user swipes left and if the user is on the last cell `myCollectionView` inserts a new cell when the user is swiping so that the user swipes left "into" the cell. And also I only allow the user to scroll one cell at a time.

**EDIT:**
So I think it is a bit hard to describe it in words so here is a gif to show what I mean

[image]

So in the past few weeks I have been trying to implement this in a number of different ways, and the one that I have found the most success with is by using the `scrollViewWillEndDragging` delegate method and I have implemented it like this:

```
 func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    // Getting the size of the cells
    let flowLayout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let cellWidth = flowLayout.itemSize.width
    let cellPadding = 10.0 as! CGFloat

    // Calculating which page "card" we should be on
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x - cellWidth/2
    print("currentOffset is \(currentOffset)")
    let cardWidth = cellWidth + cellPadding
    var page = Int(round((currentOffset)/(cardWidth) + 1))

    print("current page number is: \(page)")
    if (velocity.x < 0) {
        page -= 1

    }
    if (velocity.x > 0) {
        page += 1
    }
    print("Updated page number is: \(page)")
    print("Previous page number is: \(self.previousPage)")

    // Only allowing the user to scroll for one page!
    if(page > self.previousPage) {
        page = self.previousPage + 1
        self.previousPage = page

    }
    else if (page == self.previousPage) {
        page = self.previousPage
    }
    else {
        page = self.previousPage - 1
        self.previousPage = page
    }

    print("new page number is: " + String(page))
    print("addedCards.count + 1 is: " + String(addedCards.count + 1))
    if (page == addedCards.count) {
        print("reloading data")

        // Update data source
        addedCards.append("card")

        // Method 1
        cardCollectionView.reloadData()

        // Method 2
        //            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: addedCards.count - 1, inSection: 0)
        //            cardCollectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath])

    }
    //        print("Centering on new cell")
    // Center the cardCollectionView on the new page
    let newOffset = CGFloat(page * Int((cellWidth + cellPadding)))
    print("newOffset is: \(newOffset)")
    targetContentOffset.memory.x = newOffset

}
```

Although I think I have nearly got the desired result there are still some concerns and also bugs that I have found.

My main concern is the fact that instead of inserting a single cell at the end of `myCollectionView` I'm reloading the whole table. The reason that I do this is because if I didn't then `myCollectionView.contentOffset` wouldn't be changed and as a result when a new cell is created, `myCollectionView` isn't centered on the newly created cell.

**1.** If the user scrolls very slowly and then stops, the new cell gets created but then `myCollectionView` gets stuck in between two cells it doesn't center in on the newly created cell.

**2.** When `myCollectionView` is in between the second last cell and the last cell as a result of **1.**, the next time the user swipes right, instead of creating one single cell, two cells are created.

I've also used different ways to implement this behaviour such as using `scrollViewDidScroll`, and various other but to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction as I am kind of lost.

Here is a link to download my project if you want to see the interaction:
[My Example Project](https://github.com/kevinlu1211/CollectionViewTest)

**These the old methods if you're interested:**

To do this I have tried 2 ways,

The first being:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, 
    targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        // page is the current cell that the user is on 
        // addedCards is the array that the data source works with
        if (page == addedCards.count + 1) {
            let placeholderFlashCardProxy = FlashCardProxy(phrase: nil, pronunciation: nil, definition: nil)
            addedCards.append(placeholderFlashCardProxy)   
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: addedCards.count, inSection: 0)
            cardCollectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath])
            cardCollectionView.reloadData()

        }
}
```

The problem with using this method is that:

1. Sometimes I will get a crash as a result of: `NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.`
2. When a new `collectionCell` is added it will sometimes display the input that the user has written from the previous cell (this might have sometimes to do with the dequeuing and re-use of cell, although again, I'm not sure and I would be grateful if someone answered it)
3. The inserting isn't smooth, I want the user to be able to swipe left at the last cell and "into" a new cell. As in if I am currently on the last cell, swiping left would put me automatically at the new cell, because right now when I swipe left a new cell is created by it doesn't center on the newly created cell

The second method that I am using is:

```
let swipeLeftGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipedLeftOnCell:")
swipeLeftGestureRecognizer.direction = .Left
myCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftGestureRecognizer)
swipeLeftGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

Although the swipe gesture very rarely responds, but if I use a tap gesture, `myCollectionView` always responds which is very weird (I know again this is a question on its own)

My question is which is the better way to implement what I have described above? And if none are good what should I work with to create the desired results, I've been trying to do this for two days now and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try allowing simultaneous gestures.
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    return YES;
}

Comment: Could you elaborate on it a bit?

Comment: In the comments, above - I have pasted code. Please try and see if it works

Comment: Just tried it, there is still no response

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps out in some way :)

**UPDATE**

I updated the code to fix the issue scrolling in either direction.
The updated gist can be found here

[**New Updated Gist**](https://gist.github.com/AntonTheDev/5b47214628aee207a131c537f86b8bb8)

[**Old Gist**](https://gist.github.com/AntonTheDev/c47a4f2bb9fe9c651e8977290cb020dd)

First I'm gonna define some model to for a Card

```
class Card {
    var someCardData : String?
}
```

Next, create a collection view cell, with a card view inside that we will apply the transform to

```
class CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {

     override init(frame: CGRect) {
         super.init(frame: frame)
         self.addSubview(cardView)
         self.addSubview(cardlabel)
     }

     override func prepareForReuse() {
         super.prepareForReuse()
         cardView.alpha = 1.0
         cardView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
     }

     override func layoutSubviews() {
         super.layoutSubviews()
         cardView.frame = CGRectMake(contentPadding,
                                contentPadding,
                                contentView.bounds.width - (contentPadding * 2.0),
                                contentView.bounds.height - (contentPadding * 2.0))

         cardlabel.frame = cardView.frame
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(coder: aDecoder)
     }

     lazy var cardView : UIView = {
         [unowned self] in
         var view = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
         view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         return view
     }()

     lazy var cardlabel : UILabel = {
          [unowned self] in
          var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
          label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
          label.textAlignment = .Center
          return label
     }()
}
```

Next setup the view controller with a collection view. As you will see there is a CustomCollectionView class, which I will define near the end.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var cards = [Card(), Card()]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, tableViewHeight)
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, contentPadding)
    }

    lazy var collectionView : CollectionView = {
        [unowned self] in

        // MARK: Custom Flow Layout defined below
        var layout = CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.contentDelegate = self

        var collectionView = CollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout : layout)
        collectionView.clipsToBounds = true
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        return collectionView
        }()

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cards.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.width, tableViewHeight)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "CollectionViewCell"
        let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        // UPDATE If the cell is not the initial index, and is equal the to animating index
        // Prepare it's initial state
        if flowLayout.animatingIndex == indexPath.row  && indexPath.row != 0{
            cell.cardView.alpha = 0.0
            cell.cardView.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

UPDATED - Now For the really tricky part. I'm gonna define the CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout. The protocol callback returns the next insert index calculated by the flow layout

```
protocol CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate : class {
    func flowLayout(flowLayout : CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout, insertIndex index : NSIndexPath)
}

/**
*  Custom FlowLayout
*  Tracks the currently visible index and updates the proposed content offset
*/
class CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    weak var contentDelegate: CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate?

    // Tracks the card to be animated
    // TODO: - Adjusted if cards are deleted by one if cards are deleted
    private var animatingIndex : Int = 0

    // Tracks thje currently visible index
    private var visibleIndex : Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            if visibleIndex > oldValue  {

                if visibleIndex > animatingIndex {
                    // Only increment the animating index forward
                    animatingIndex = visibleIndex
                }

                if visibleIndex + 1 > self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0) - 1 {
                    let currentEntryIndex =  NSIndexPath(forRow: visibleIndex + 1, inSection: 0)
                    contentDelegate?.flowLayout(self, insertIndex: currentEntryIndex)
                }

            } else if visibleIndex < oldValue && animatingIndex == oldValue {
                // if we start panning to the left, and the animating index is the old value
                // let set the animating index to the last card.
                animatingIndex = oldValue + 1
            }
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
        self.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // The width offset threshold percentage from 0 - 1
    let thresholdOffsetPrecentage : CGFloat = 0.5

    // This is the flick velocity threshold
    let velocityThreshold : CGFloat = 0.4

    override func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        let leftThreshold = CGFloat(collectionView!.bounds.size.width) * ((CGFloat(visibleIndex) - 0.5))
        let rightThreshold = CGFloat(collectionView!.bounds.size.width) * ((CGFloat(visibleIndex) + 0.5))

        let currentHorizontalOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset.x

        // If you either traverse far enought in either direction,
        // or flicked the scrollview over the horizontal velocity in either direction,
        // adjust the visible index accordingly

        if currentHorizontalOffset < leftThreshold || velocity.x < -velocityThreshold {
            visibleIndex = max(0 , (visibleIndex - 1))
        } else if currentHorizontalOffset > rightThreshold || velocity.x > velocityThreshold {
            visibleIndex += 1
        }

        var _proposedContentOffset = proposedContentOffset
        _proposedContentOffset.x = CGFloat(collectionView!.bounds.width) * CGFloat(visibleIndex)

        return _proposedContentOffset
    }
}
```

And define the delegate methods in your view controller to insert a new card when the delegate tell it that it needs a new index

```
extension ViewController : CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate {
    func flowLayout(flowLayout : CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout, insertIndex index : NSIndexPath) {
        cards.append(Card())
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([index])
        }) { (complete) in

    }
}
```

And below is the custom Collection view that applies the animation while scrolling accordingly :)

```
class CollectionView : UICollectionView {

    override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
        didSet {
            if self.tracking {
                // When you are tracking the CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout does not update it's visible index until you let go
                // So you should be adjusting the second to last cell on the screen
                self.adjustTransitionForOffset(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.numberOfItemsInSection(0) - 1, inSection: 0))
            } else {

                // Once the CollectionView is not tracking, the CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout calls
                // targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(_:withScrollingVelocity:), and updates the visible index
                // by adding 1, thus we need to continue the trasition on the second the last cell
                self.adjustTransitionForOffset(NSIndexPath(forRow:  self.numberOfItemsInSection(0) - 2, inSection: 0))
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     This method applies the transform accordingly to the cell at a specified index
     - parameter atIndex: index of the cell to adjust
     */
    func adjustTransitionForOffset(atIndex : NSIndexPath) {
        if let lastCell = self.cellForItemAtIndexPath(atIndex) as? CollectionViewCell {
            let progress = 1.0 - (lastCell.frame.minX - self.contentOffset.x) / lastCell.frame.width
            lastCell.cardView.alpha = progress
            lastCell.cardView.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, progress, progress, 0.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello this looks promising I will look at it later today :)

Comment: @YellowPillow Just let me know if I can help out in any way, or make the answer better :)

Comment: so I just implemented everything works fine when creating the cells, but when swiping back the cells that were created aren't shown. Hard to explain but to reproduce this, first create a few cells by swiping left, then after they are created swipe right. Hopefully you will see what I mean, I'm going to try to fix it but just thought you might want to know :)

Comment: @YellowPillow I think you just need set the transform to identity and the alpha to 1 by overriding prepareForReuse. I'll take a look in the office here

Comment: @YellowPillow I updated the code and appended a new gist. It was definitely an interesting problem to solve, threw me for a loop, but finally figured it out :)

Comment: I'll look at it soon sorry I'm a bit busy now! You're a magician though please teach me your ways! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @YellowPillow check out Nike Tech Book :P I got an animation engine called FlightAnimator in the works right now, all it needs is documentation. I haven't made public yet, but when I do it's gonna rival Facebook's POP

Comment: The app looks amazing! If you need with help documenting the code in the future I would be honored to help and read the code :)

Comment: @YellowPillow check this thing out, it's slowly coming along :) https://github.com/AntonTheDev/FlightAnimator/blob/dev/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I think u missed one point here in

`let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: addedCards.count, inSection: 0)`

the indexPath should be

`NSIndexPath(forItem : addedCards.count - 1, inSection : 0)` not `addedCards.count`

Thats why you were getting the error

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0
```